# Page on background tab not loading properly

Tags: jquery, ajax, polymer, polymer-1.0

I am using Polymer 1.0 with jQuery and have created a small single page app. When I "Open link in new tab", however, the page doesn't load. More specifically, it loads in template form and fires the ajax requests to get the data, but none of that data gets populated into the template. For example, a simplified version:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    url = '/ajax/get_data';
    $.post(url, '', function(data) {
      if (data.data.id !== undefined & data.data.id > 0) {
        $('.gt-info-location').text(data.data.name);
        $('.gt-city-population').text(data.population);
        $('.gt-city-timezone').text(data.data.timezone);
        $('.gt-city-county').text(data.data.county);
        $('google-map')[0].latitude = data.data.latitude;
        $('google-map')[0].longitude = data.data.longitude;
        $('#location-frontpage').css('background',"url('pictures/"+data.data.image_file+"') center / cover");
        $('#location-back').css('background',"url('pictures/"+data.data.image_file+"') center / cover");
      }
    });
});
```

I know the `$.post` is happening and returning the correct data from the web request log, but none of the `.text()` or `.css()` functions are making any changes to the page. And, yes, loading the same page in an open tab works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a little hacky, but I put everything I'd been doing on `.ready()` into a function called `loadDataAndPopulateToken()` and then in addition to running that function on `.ready()` I also bound it to window focusing:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  // initial token load (doesn't work if in background tab)
  loadDataAndPopulateToken();

  // reload the token data whenever the page comes into focus
  window.onfocus = loadDataAndPopulateToken;
});
```

The downside to this approach is that it reloads all the data whenever the tab passes out of focus and then back into it.